# wordpress text domain issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

so i testing my them from errs with theme check plugin 
and go the text domain issue but it returns a blank value ! is this make any since !!

```html
REQUIRED: This theme text domain does not match the theme's slug. The text domain used: This theme's correct slug and text-domain is osiris-rathemes.


/*
Theme Name: osiris rathemes
Theme URI: https://themeforest.net/user/ra-themes/portfolioa
Author: Mohamed Said
Author URI: https://themeforest.net/user/ra-themes
Description: some dec
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: osiris-rathemes

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

theme folder name as the text domain 
and the style.css have the text domain and its not an empty string

do i miss any thing !

Comment: after a question, usually you use the question mark ? no !

Comment: **do i miss any thing** : yes, the code

Comment: @madalinivascu lol

Comment: Please add the declaration section of your style.css file.

Comment: @madalinivascu yo mate you hilarious :D

Comment: what's your folder name for your theme?

Comment: see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198292/how-can-i-see-my-themes-text-domain

Comment: @madalinivascu my folder name are the same "osiris-rathemes"

Comment: from the message, your text domain seems to be blank **The text domain used: This**

Comment: yeah this what confusing me , even when am trying to put a wrong text domain so i could see another err i don't and i get the same err as blank one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158826/discussion-between-mohamed-saed-and-madalinivascu).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to load the theme textdomain in the functions.php file.  Your style.css file looks correct but I don't know what your theme plugin checker is doing..

```
function osiris_rathemes_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'osiris-rathemes', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'osiris_rathemes_setup' );
```

Comment: Check the source code or ask the plugin developer what it's checking that needs to be present.